# Audio visualisation while recording

Tags: android, audio-recording, bar-chart, visualizer

I would like to show a bar graph visualisation while recording audio. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer for a full example of developing a visualizer on Android. This uses the MediaPlayer to play, although you should be able to hook it up to your audio recorder

Comment: how do we hook it up to the AurdioRecord object?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading about [Visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html). You can represent your audio either as a Waveform data or a Frequency data.

Also see [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html). It includes a sample code for creating a Visualizer.

Hope it helps

Cheers